# start brew cask apps from terminal

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I installed signal using brew cask (`brew cask install signal`)

I would like to be able to start the GUI app from terminal by typing `signal`(e.g.: to run the GUI of emacs [installed using brew cask] I can type `emacs`)

Maybe there is a way to edit the cask file to create this link?

I understand that I can create an alias in my zsh config file, but I was wondering if that is the correct approach.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `open` to open any app on macOS, it's not related to homebrew, but you can extend your integration as you see fit. Example: `open -a signal`.